# Calculating $\int_\gamma \frac{1}{1+z^2}\,dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I calculate $\int_\gamma \frac{1}{1+z^2}\,dz$, where $\gamma$ is the straight line from $1$ to $1+i$, using primitive functions?

I know that $\arctan z$ is a primitive for that function, but how to calculate it for complex values such as $1+i$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What've you tried?

Comment: I know that $\arctan z$ is a primitive for that function, but I'm not sure how to calculate it for complex values.

Comment: What do you mean by calculate arctan? Writ it using some more "elementary" function? Do you think that logarithms are simpler to work with?

Comment: What's a primitive function?

Comment: @RudytheReindeer "[primitive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_function)" is sometimes used as a synonym for "antiderivative".

Comment: @Tom-Tom Great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can parametrize $\gamma (t)=1+it$ as the line going from $1$ to $1+i$ then use $\int_{\gamma} f(z)=\int_a^b f(\gamma (t))\gamma'(t) dt$

 Using the above parametrization you get $\int_0^1 \frac {idt}{1+(1+it)^2}=\arctan(1+i)-\pi/4$

 
You can get $\arctan(z)=\frac 12 i(\ln(1+iz)-\ln(1-iz))$

but that sounds harder than just putting $\arctan(1+i)$ into a computing software.